# should trees in an ensemble be trained on samples of the same size?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, sampling

I know that if `bootstrap=True`, then "for each tree, N samples are drawn randomly with replacement from the training set and the tree is built on this new version of the training data. This introduces randomness in the training procedure since trees will each be trained on slightly different training sets. In expectation, drawing N samples with replacement from a dataset of size N will select ~2/3 unique samples from the original set".

But why can't we train trees for choices of different sizes, with different class balances?

In all known ensemble methods (boosting, random forest, etc.), individual estimators are trained on samples of the same size, I don’t understand why.

Comment: Your question(s) are too broad. XGBoost also does seeded-random subsampling subsample (rows and/or columns). Is your choice of algorithm fixed (RF)? Is your training-set size fixed, and you're trying to maximize some criterion (e.g. accuracy on 20% holdout-set)? If so, which criterion? *"Why can't we train trees for choices of different sizes, with different class balance"* You can. Are you only asking how to do it with XGBoost? RF? GBT in general? Are you asking for a suggested algorithm? or just the options on scikit RF? RF probably isn't the best for that.

Comment: @smci I'm trying to understand if there are any methodological limitations to train estimators on different samples, both diffeternt in terms of class ratio and size?

Comment: But you haven't answered any of the things I asked.

Comment: @smci Ok. Let's focus on a random forest. No, training size is not fixed for each of estimators in ensemble. But whether it is correct to train a random forest on subsamples of different sizes and with different class ratios from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: Well, when you say "different class (im)balances" is this 2-class classification? or n-class classification? and what are the class ratios? approx 1:1, or very imbalanced? If we had three classes with 90:9:1 ratios then 3 trees would be like one-against-all.

Comment: Look at existing Q&A on *trees imbalance* on the sister sites [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=trees+imbalance+score%3A3) and DataScience.SE. For example [this answer on CV.SE to "Is Random Forest a good option for unbalanced data classification?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/242871/7291), [DS.SE: Unbalanced multiclass data with XGBoost](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16342/unbalanced-multiclass-data-with-xgboost)

Comment: But, you still need to tell us now many classes? and what are the class ratios? How many exemplars (rows) do you have for your smallest class(es)? And what metric are you trying to optimize? (class-weighted accuracy? class-weighted logloss? etc. on a 20% holdout set).